# 'no module found' error in Python 3.9 for windows 10

Tags: import, module

I'm a total beginner in Python, I'm reading 'Learning Python' by Mark Lutz and following along in the book.  I created a file called 'script1.py', saved as an 'all files' (as opposed to a .txt file) in notepad.  The name of the file, code, etc. is verbatim to that which the book instructs.

I know script1.py is there and works, I know this because when I enter 'py script1.py' in my command prompt or git bash, it correctly outputs the product of the code.

The book instructs me to run 'import script1' in Python.  When I do, I get the 'module not found' error.  I've tried importing as stated above, a from-import command, moving 'script1' to and from different directories.  I confirmed my PATH was set up to support python, nothing.

It seems (to my UNtrained eye anyway) that python isn't finding my files.  Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that you can only import python files into a python program. In your File Explorer, make sure that file extensions are shown and verify that your script is script1.py and not script1.py.txt or something of that sort.